# Здраствуйте, возникает ошибка при загрузке фото.

Tags: php

Здраствуйте, возникает ошибка при загрузке фото.

Ошибка 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in Z:\home\crape.com\www\upload.php on line 20`

Проверяю на Локальном сервере.

Сам php обработчик

```
 <?php
      define('UPLOAD_FILE', 'upload/images/');
      $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif","jpeg"); // допустимые форматы
         if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") // пришел запрос
            {
              $name = $_FILES['file']['name'] ; // имя файла
              $size = $_FILES['file']['size'] ; // размер файла
          if(strlen($name))
             {
               list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name) ; // разбиваем на имя и формат
               if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))    // смотрим формат такой как мы разрешили?!
              {
                if($size < (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) // Ограничиваем размер файла в 1MB
               {   
              $actual_image_name = time() . "." . $ext ; // задаем уникальное имя файлу
              $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
              if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, UPLOAD_FILE . '/' . $actual_image_name)) // переносим файл с tmp в наш каталог
              {
              echo "<img src=\"" . UPLOAD_FILE . "/{$actual_image_name}\" class=\"preview\" alt="JavaScript: Загрузка картинок с помощью jQuery и PHP" /> "; // показываем превьюшку
           User::UploadUserAvatar($UserId, $username, $actual_image_name) ;
                                     }
                                    else echo "Ошибка. =(";
                                     }
                                    else echo "Максимальный размер файла не должен превышать 1MB"; 
                                }
                                else echo "Допустимые форматы: jpg|jpeg|png|gif)"; 
                            }
                            else die("Пожалуйста выберите изображение!") ;
                        }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alt="JavaScript: Загрузка картинок с помощью jQuery и PHP"
```

Не экранировали кавычки. А надо бы.

Comment: alt=\"JavaScript: Загрузка картинок с помощью jQuery и PHP\" 

Благодарю.